# How to include a php page to ajax function success

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to include a PHP file inside the ajax success function.
Is it possible to add a PHP file inside the ajax function?
My PHP file is list.php
My ajax function is :

```
function fn_nextitem(sliderNo){
    
  $.get("/index.php?op=ajax", {slide_no:sliderNo},function(resp) {
    if (resp) {
     obj_b = JSON.parse(resp);
     if(obj_b) {
      $('#Div').html(obj_b);
    }
   else {
  
   } 
}
```

My PHP code is like:

```
if(!empty($items )){  
          foreach ($items as $itemid => $info) ;
            $html = include(TEMPLATE_PATH . "/list.php");
          endforeach; 
    echo json_encode('data_arr'=>$html);
  }
```

After adding this code I didn't get any results. But if I assign the **'$items'** to '**data_arr**' then I got the result.
I want to include this PHP page inside the **for loop.**

Comment: `include` doesn't return anything by default, it just executes the PHP file requested. I can't see your template files so I don't know what goes on in them but please read the manual for [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), specifically where it says _"Handling Returns: include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1. It is possible to execute a return statement inside an included file in order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script which called it"_

Comment: In template file contains <div> with display item details such as name, image,price etc. My concern is Is it possible to add a PHP page or this template to my ajax function using json_encode. I am trying to do that.

Comment: Well including html in JSON doesn't make much sense. If you want to return HTML, just echo some HTML and forget about JSON.

Comment: I don't want to append the template file contents under the ajax function, because it is a lengthy file. So I think, when I add this content to my ajax function, it takes some delay to display the page

Comment: Yes, I just append my html in ajax function success. I got the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
function fn_nextitem(sliderNo){
    
  $.get("/index.php?op=ajax", {slide_no:sliderNo},function(resp) {
    if (resp) {
     
     
      $('#Div').append(resp);
    }
   else {
  
   } 
}
```

My PHP code is like:

```
if(!empty($items )){  
          foreach ($items as $itemid => $info) ;
            $html = include(TEMPLATE_PATH . "/list.php");
          endforeach; 
    
  }
```

After that, I got my desired result.